# Drag 'n Drop Element targeting

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, targeting

so i was programming (with a friend) a Drag 'n Drop system with elements (here buttons) for HTML in plain JS. Then i realised, what if i have multiple element on this page? Answer: All these are being affected. So i said... okay! i just increasingly add a value to the id, then the whole thing won't interfere.

So now I've got the Problem, that i can't know which element is being targeted... or better: which id is being targeted.

PS: Please JS only no JQuery and no Frameworks.

PPS: (I already looked through Stackoverflow etc for this situation, nothing very suiting to my case, at least i didn't found one)

```
    var pressed = 0;

    function drag(state){
        if(state == true){
           pressed = 1;
        }
        else{
           pressed = 0;
        }
    }
  var obj = "";
    onmousemove = function(a){
        if(pressed == 1){
    obj = document.getElementById("move1"); //<-- This var (obj) needs to be "flexible" to any element, not only the element with the id "move1"
            var x = a.clientX - parseInt(obj.style.width) / 2;
            var y = a.clientY - parseInt(obj.style.height) / 2;
            obj.style.left = x + "px";
            obj.style.top = y + "px";
        }
    }

var counter = 0;

function createbutton() {
counter++;
document.getElementById("surface").innerHTML += "<button id = 'move" + counter + "' style = 'width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; border: none; position: fixed;' onmousedown = 'drag(true)' onmouseup = 'drag(false)' onClick = 'drag(false)'>Move this Button</button>";
}
```

`
Note: This doesn't include HTML because somehow Stackoverflow does not show properly, so only JS, pls visit JSFiddle to see full (create multiple Buttons and drag the last one!): https://jsfiddle.net/2nyc4a83/

Comment: I just fixed your problem.. will upload a jsfiddle in a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new parameter to your function **drag()**. On the events **onmousedown**, **onmouseup** and **onClick** the **id** of the current object will be used as an argument for **drag()**. Example for how this looks in the code: `<button ... onmousedown = 'drag(true, this.id)'>Move this button</button>`

The **id** will then be saved in a global variable so that you can later access it in the onmousemove function like this:

```
obj = document.getElementById(obj_id);
```

[-> jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w23jxyuz/)